# Weird malloc error in C, tokenizing words

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to tokenize a word by spaces and quotes, but I am getting a weird malloc error, after the correct output.

I want this function to accept something like :

```
hello world "SOme quote"
```

and the output should be :

```
hello
world
"some quote"
```

or if the input is:

```
hello world no quote
```

the output should be:

```
hello
world
no
quote
```

<strike>however right now, I am getting:</strike>

```
Hello
WOrld
"Hello World"
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001760010 ***
a.out: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It seems like the output is right, but then it messes up after

The code is:

```
int process_command(char command[80]){
char curr_char;
char *word;
int start_pos;
int i;
int len;
len = strlen(command);
for(i=0,start_pos=0;i<strlen(command);i++){
    curr_char = command[i];
    if (curr_char == ' '){
        if (command[i-1]==' ') {start_pos++;continue;}
        word = malloc(i-start_pos*(sizeof(char)));
        strncpy(word,command+start_pos,i-start_pos);
        printf("%s\n",word);
        free(word);

        start_pos =i+1;

    }
    else if (curr_char == '\"'){
        word= malloc(len-i*(sizeof(char)));
        strncpy(word,command+i,len);
        printf("%s\n",word);
        free(word);
        i=len+len;
    }

}

return 0;
}
int main(){
    char buffer[80] = "Hello   WOrld  \"Hello World\"";
    process_command(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem was fixed! thanks
Heres the updated code:

```
int process_command(char command[80]){
char curr_char;
char *word;
int start_pos;
int i;
int len;
int quote=0;
len = strlen(command);
for(i=0,start_pos=0;i<strlen(command);i++){
    curr_char = command[i];
    if (curr_char == ' '){      /*If there was a space found copy the stuff before the space*/
        if ( i>0 && command[i-1]==' ') {
            start_pos++;
            continue;
        }
        word = malloc(i-start_pos+1*(sizeof(char)));
        strncpy(word,command+start_pos,i-start_pos);
        word[i-start_pos+1]='\0';
        printf("%s\n",word);
        free(word);
        start_pos =i+1;

    }
    else if (curr_char == '\"'){        /*If a quote was found, copy the rest of the string and exit loop*/
        word= malloc(len-i+1*(sizeof(char)));
        strncpy(word,command+i,len-i);
        word[len-i+1]='\0';
        printf("%s\n",word);
        free(word);
        quote=1;
        break;
    }

}if (quote==0){                 /*If there was no quote in the string, get the last element*/
    word = malloc(len-start_pos+1*(sizeof (char)));
    strncpy(word,command+start_pos,len-start_pos);
    word[len-start_pos+1]='\0';
    printf("%s\n",word);
        free (word);
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    char buffer[80] = "Hello   \"WOrld  test\"";
    process_command(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

However, I am wondering if this is an efficient way of tokenizing? 
This is to process user typed instructions. So if the user types

```
add 1 2 "SOme text"
```

I want to tokenize the query to three parts and then process it. So to do that I am tokenizing it, and pushing them into a queue, where at later times I can pop the item out one by one and process it.

Comment: Your updated code still has several latent bugs, even if they don't show up in your tests. For example, `strncpy()` is not properly terminating your temporary strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be sure to allocate enough memory for the strncpy you're going to do.
These two lines are off by one, because `strncpy` writes a zero byte as well:

```
word = malloc(i-start_pos*(sizeof(char)));
strncpy(word,command+start_pos,i-start_pos);
```

These two lines make no sense:  you allocate len-i bytes, then write len bytes (plus the zero byte) to it:

```
word = malloc(len-i*(sizeof(char)));
strncpy(word,command+i,len);
```

Comment: The second one, I am allocating len-i bytes to get the total length of string - where I found the quote.
Then i copy from command+i.. where the quote was found to the end of the string.
Shouldn't that work?

Comment: Better yet, *don't use `strncpy()`*. It can either needlessly copy extra null characters to the target or leave the target unterminated. It's not really a string function.

Comment: @user1411893: the third argument to strncpy is the number of bytes to copy.

Comment: ah offcourse, thanks! fixed
@KeithThompson What would you recommend for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems, some of which are:

```
for(i=0,start_pos=0;i<strlen(command);i++){
    curr_char = command[i];
    if (curr_char == ' '){
        if (command[i-1]==' ') {start_pos++;continue;}      // accesses an invalid array offset when i == 0
        word = malloc(i-start_pos*(sizeof(char)));          // doesn't allocate space for null terminator
        strncpy(word,command+start_pos,i-start_pos);        // doesn't null terminate the string
        printf("%s\n",word);
        free(word);

        start_pos =i+1;

    }
    else if (curr_char == '\"'){
        word= malloc(len-i*(sizeof(char)));                 // doesn't allocate space for null terminator
        strncpy(word,command+i,len);                        // writes past the end of the allocated buffer
        printf("%s\n",word);
        free(word);
        i=len+len;                                          // not sure what the intent of this is?  use `break;`?
    }

}
```

In general, `strncpy()` should be avoided because it doesn't always do what users expect, so it's often involved in buggy code.

Also, your quote handling is pretty simplistic - it assumes that the quoted item is always the last token in the string.  That might be what you intend, but it won't work for a set of tokens like:

```
"one and two" three
```

Comment: I don't care about that case for my program. If a " is quote, I want to push that entire string until the end to the queue, and check for errors when I process it. Its just so that I can handle a quote within a quote like :
"one and two " three"